# requestImageDataForAsset with video PHAsset returns with imageData pointing a photo

Tags: ios, photokit, ios-9-beta3

iOS9.3beta3,

PHImageManager requestImageDataForAsset returns with imageData pointing to a photo although the PHAssert is a **video** asset which was captured on the device.

Documentation [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:):

> "requestImageDataForAsset(_:options:resultHandler:)
>
> ... If the version option is set to PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent,
> Photos provides rendered image data, including the results of any edits that have been made to the asset content. Otherwise, Photos provides the
> **originally captured image data for the asset**."

Is that a bug in iOS9.3 ?

amir.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for me

```
+ (void)getAssetData:(NSString *)ident completeBlock:(void (^)(NSData *assetData))completeBlock {
    PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[ident] options:nil];
    if (fetchResult && [fetchResult count] == 0) {
        if (completeBlock) {
            completeBlock(nil);
        }
        return;
    }

    PHAsset *asset = fetchResult.firstObject;
    if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeVideo) {
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
            if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
                AVURLAsset* urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
                NSNumber *size;
                [urlAsset.URL getResourceValue:&size forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAsset.URL];
                completeBlock(data);
            } else {
                completeBlock(nil);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:fetchResult.firstObject options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            completeBlock(imageData);
        }];
    }
}
```